# miniruby Permission denied Error occurred when installing ruby 2.3.1 using rbenv installed homebrew

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv, ruby-2.3

I got error message when installing ruby 2.3.1 using rbenv.
My environment is below.

- MacOS 10.10.5
- rbenv 1.0.0

The log message is below.

```
$ rbenv install 2.3.1

...

Last 10 log lines:
compiling enc/unicode.c
compiling enc/utf_8.c
compiling enc/trans/newline.c
linking miniruby
generating encdb.h
make: ./miniruby: Permission denied
make: ./miniruby: Permission denied
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [encdb.h] Error 1
```

If you get the same error, would you please tell me how to solve this error?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: try using sudo before your install command

Comment: @archon92 Thank you for your message. I think rbenv installs in local environemnt without sudo. Is it incorrect?

Comment: I am not entirely sure about that,But usually ruby make requires write permissions to specific folders and the error you are getting definitely says that

Comment: I solved this issue executing via sudo user. Thank you archon92.

Comment: Why do I have to append an `sudo` before `rbenv install 2.4.0`? I thought rbenv is installing everything into my `~/.rbenv`, isn't that the truth?

I think prefixing install command with `sudo` defeat the purpose of having rbenv in home folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accepted answer is not a good answer - the install process should not require root privileges, and may lead to problems installing gems that require C extensions in the future (nokogiri is a good example).

It's a documented bug in the `ruby-build` package: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/992, the workaround is to navigate into the working directory and run `make install` yourself - which should run if you have XCode command line tools installed and updated.

Comment: for anyone else who was a little lost. the directory to run the make command may lie inside ~/.rvm/... ruby-x or ~/.rbenv/.../ruby-x. good luck

Answer (score -2):

add sudo before the command(To give the admin permission to install)

> ex)sudo make ruby 2.3.1

Comment: wrote above, I can resolve this issue. Thank you viodrey.